# Cloudflare rewrite multiple changes

Tags: url, url-rewriting, transform, cloudflare, rules

I'm trying to rewrite a URL with Cloudflare Transform Rule but I need it to make two changes and I also want it to behave according to a regular expression.

For example:

https://test1-**server**.cloud.servers/**account**/login

Should be rewritten to:

https://test1-**machine**.cloud.servers/**forms**/login

And

https://prod2-**server**.cloud.servers/**account**/login

Should be rewritten to:

https://prod2-**machine**.cloud.servers/**forms**/login

Could this be done with Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this, although it may be more complicated than just a transform rule. With the transform rule, you can only change the *path* of the final request it seems -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/url-rewrite/examples

So, I don't think changing the subdomain is possible. However, in theory if both your subdomains are pointed at the same IP address, you could a "Request Header Modification" rule to intercept and update the `host` header value -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/request-header-modification/examples

So your condition would be the same for both rules, but in the request header rule, you'd be changing the host header to `test1-machine.cloud.servers`.

Here are all available functions you can make use of (for all transform rule types) -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-firewall-language/functions#transformation-functions

Comment: You can change the subdomain from a transform rule.
I'm not sure how to write it so that I can keep whatever is in the regular expression.
For example:
https://[regex1]-server.blah/blah
to
https://[regex1]-machine.blah/blah